# working with internet explorer windows that are protected by invincea

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a script that normally works with Internet Explorer, but, since the company put an application called "Invincea" on everyone's computer, it appears the script unable to read the window titles. Any suggestions?

Previous code for IE without Invincea:

```
URL = "http://nameofmysite.com"
Window = "My Site"

Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set WShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
URLFound = False
Set objShellWindows = objShell.Windows
    'To Fix Item Not Found Error
For Each objIE In objShell.Windows
Next

For I = 0 To objShellWindows.Count - 1
    Set objIE = objShellWindows.Item(I)
    On Error Resume Next
    If InStr(UCase(objShellWindows.Item(I).FullName), "IEXPLORE.EXE") Then
       If Err.Number = 0 Then
          If InStr(objShellWindows.Item(I).Document.Title, (Window)) Then
             URLFound = True
             Exit For
          End If
       End If
    End If
Next
```

This code doesn't work if IE is protected by Invincea.  I altered the code thinking it would work, but it doesn't:

```
URL = "http://nameofmysite.com"
Window = "My Site - Protected by Invincea"
```

Hopefully someone has ran into this.

Comment: talk to invincea and/or your sysadmins. don't try to subvert a corporate-mandated security system.

Comment: I'm not trying to hack into the system or anything. These are macros/applications that have been working fine until Invincea was introduced. Now they're not. Users have the option to use old means of pulling up IE and using these programs, but we have been told we need to find alternative means to use the same programs with Invincea.

Comment: exactly... talk to the sysadmins and see if this is a configurable option in the security package. if the secapp is disallowing this information, then there's nothing you can really do about it.